# How can I read character by character from a text file in QT C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextstream

I want to read from a text file  like simple C++'s fgetc but with QT QTextStream where I tried readall method but it skip the last characther which probably is a break.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [read](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#read) method and set max number of characters for reading.

```
    QString oneChar = stream.read(1);
```

or can use overload operator >> for QChar. Something like this

```
    QChar oneChar = '';
    stream >> oneChar;
```

Comment: and how can I get the  size of the file to know when to stop or is there an EOF possibility?

Comment: @user3540983 you can do it in while loop

        while (!stream.atEnd())

Comment: Moreover you can use a for loop with your QString and do for(QChar mychar = mystring.begin() ; mychar != mystring.end() ; ++char) { qDebug() << *mychar; } and you sould see all your string char by char.